# how to change php and xdebug versions of Vagrant (VDD) VM?

Tags: ruby, drupal, virtual-machine, vagrant, chef-infra

I have installed a vagrant drupal development VM.
I do not quite get how the config of my VM can be changed, using vagrant chef or vagrantfiles?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to set it is in the included `config.json` file.

Look for:

```
"php": {
    "version": false
  },
```

Change `false` value to the version you want.

Comment: The described configuration has no effect and it seems that this feature is currently not supported in VDD Version 8.x, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2731389

Answer (score 1):

Read through the Chef recipes to see how it installs php, change whatever needs to be changed.

Comment: could u please give me more details. i have located a /chef/cookbooks/berks/php/recipes/source.rb that contains version = node['php']['version']
whatever i change in version variable , after doing vagrant halt, vagrant up, php --version it keeps give me php5.3.6

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Drupal VDD uses the Opscode PHP cookbook:
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/php

I read that cookbook by default will install whatever PHP versions are available to your system's packaging tools (apt, yum).  I.e. if the specified version of PHP isn't available to apt/yum, it will likely just install the latest version.

To override this, you can try telling the cookbook to install from source, e.g.

```
"php": {
    "version": "5,3",
    "install_method": "source"
},
```